# Can not connect to wifi in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I just installed Ubuntu 12 desktop on a Dell Inspiron N3010. The machine is intel i3 and originally came with Windows 7 system. I can not see any of the available Wifi. My wireless network is ok in other non ubuntu machines. In Ubuntu, I could connect to the Internet using wired network only. I am new to Ubuntu. Please, let me know how to troubleshoot the problem step by step. How can I know if the wireless adapter driver is installed properly? What command should I try?

Answer (score 1):

1. check that your wireless is switched on go to "system settings" (in the right top corner where you also switch off) --> "network" and check the options for wireless
2. your wireless network might be hidden try to click on the network icon and connect to hidden networks
3. to check if your wireless adapter is working properly you can test it with "system testing" just choose the test you want to do (to come there just hit your windows key and type sys --> and the icon should show up)

hope it helps